# An expression or saying meaning "don't celebrate too early"

Tags: popular-refrains

I am looking for a saying or common expression to say that it is not advisable to anticipate or celebrate something before you know the actual outcome. I am thinking about political elections or football match results, but also more everyday expectations about a possible positive outcome.

Comment: Lots of good answers already. The OP's idea of breaking into a celebration too early has its own charm and none of the known idioms comes even close in the impact that 'celebrate too early' has, though.

Comment: @Kris - I put "celebrate" in inverted commas and in the body I say also "anticipate". The idea is to give for granted something in anticipation but not necessarily make official celebration about it.

Comment: I know. "Publicly acknowledge (a significant or happy day or event) with a social gathering or enjoyable activity" -- the party is incidental, not necessary :)

Comment: Dutch has a great one for this: "De huid verkopen voor de beer geschoten is" or: "Selling the skin before the bear has been shot". (There's also a wrong letter-switched version that effectively means the same thing: "De buit verkopen voor de heer geschoten is" = "Selling the loot before the gentleman has been shot".)

Comment: @mcv: Nice spoonerism.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to answer this question, but I think "Never laugh at live dragons," from *The Hobbit*, fits this question nicely.

Comment: It ain't over 'til the fat lady sings.

Comment: Just a thought.  A lot of these expressions below become very "akward" depending on the situation.  if it were a husband telling his wife not to call everyone to say they are pregnant because of a home test....he thinks to wait until the doctor does the test.  Telling her to "Not count her chickens..." that would sound awful

Comment: "Don't count your chickens before they hatch" is common in the US

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Don't sell the skin before you've caught the bear*.

*Never sell the bear's skin before one has killed the beast*.

*The die hasn't been cast (yet)*.

*The final/last word hasn't been said/spoken*.

*It hasn't all been said yet*.

*It ain't (all) over (and done) yet*.

*One must not be too hasty in one's rejoicing*.

Comment: The Chinese say 'Don't sell your ox till you've found a horse'.

Comment: Is this *bear* variant idiomatic in English ? We have that one just litterally in french language [too](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-is-an-equivalent-idiom-in-french-for-the-english-expression-not-over-until).

Comment: @RomainVALERI Polish also has a closely related idiom: to portion/divide the skin while it's still on the bear (dzielić skórę na niedźwiedziu).

Comment: "The man that once did sell the lion's skin / While the beast lived, was killed with hunting him." --Shakespeare, *Henry V.* But the quotation or proverb is not so familiar that I would venture the first line alone and expect someone else to get the point.

Comment: I confirm the first (bear's skin) exists also in italian. We also have another: don't put the wagon in front of the oxes. I wonder if there's something similar in english.

Comment: @Frazz, there is a phrase in English "putting the cart before the horse", which refers to putting things in the wrong order, or poorly prioritising them. I don't think it would typically be used to mean "don't celebrate too early" though.

Comment: It ain't over till the fat lady sings.

Answer (score 75):

I think this is a useful saying that may fit what you are looking for

[Don't count your chickens](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Don%27t+count+chickens) (before they're hatched)

> something that you say in order to warn someone to wait until a good thing they are expecting has really happened before they make any plans about it: *You might be able to get a loan from the bank, but don't count your chickens.*

Comment: Absolutely right                      .

Comment: This is a common saying in Latin America as well. Very useful — although this is the first time I've heard it in English.

Comment: Old joke: There was a plot to kill the king, and a noble was discovered to be in on it. They brought in the executioner, but the king offered to spare his life if he'd give up his conspirators. Then noble proudly fixed his jaw, so the king nodded to the executioner. Seeing this, the noble shouted, "I'll tell! I'll tell!" But it was too late and the executioner's axe cut off both the words and the head of the traitor. And the moral of the story is: *Don't hatchet your counts before they chicken.*

Answer (score 18):

"It isn't over [till the fat lady sings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/it-isn%27t-over-till-the-fat-lady-sings)".

Also, "It isn't over till it's over". (Politicians and journalists in Britain and America alike trot out this platitude all the time when elections are on.)

Comment: Whether you like the "grammar" or not, the actual expression is [*It **ain't** over till the fat lady sings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_ain't_over_till_the_fat_lady_sings)

Comment: I've never heard the "ain't" version before.  Maybe it's because we don't use "ain't" over here...

Answer (score 12):

"Don't [speak too soon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/speak+too+soon?s=t)" - could also work here.

> **speak too soon**
>
> Assume something prematurely, as in I guess I **spoke too soon** about
>   moving to Boston; I didn't get the job after all .

Answer (score 12):

And then there's the Yogi-ism, *It ain't over till it's over.*

Yogi-isms are the sayings of Yogi Berra,a famous baseball player and manager. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra

Comment: I think you mean Lenny Kravitz! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Ain't_Over_'til_It's_Over

Comment: Well, sure. Him too.

Comment: "I really didn't say everything I said" - Yogi Berra.

Comment: Right @ Andrew Grimm. He said that too--or did he?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other good answers, there's also:

> [There's many a slip twixt the cup and the lip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_many_a_slip_twixt_the_cup_and_the_lip)

Answer (score 3):

**To keep a lid on it** is used in Australia and the UK, to mean to not get carried away by the euphoria or early or temporary success.

Note this phrase can also mean simply to keep quiet about something, or to keep something a secret.

Comment: Hm. I'd say that "keep a lid on it" **only** means to keep quiet about something. Though I suppose things might be different Down Under.

Comment: US: this phrase means to be discreet around these parts.

Answer (score 3):

> Don't jinx it.

According to superstition, a jinx is someone who always brings bad luck; "jinxing it" implies that talking about recent good luck can ruin the good luck and can bring about bad luck before the outcome is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's more common to say:

> *Don't celebrate too soon*

than to use *early*.

I think most of these other possible answers are either a bit too general, or off target in terms of celebration. I prefer:

> ***Keep the champagne on ice***

It implies there will be celebrating in the near and foreseeable future, but not immediately, so we will continue to keep the bubbly on ice.

However, it could also be used ironically or derisively, to burst another's bubble if they seem to be a bit too optimistic.

Comment: That saying means 'prepare to celebrate' rather than 'don't celebrate too soon'

Answer (score 1):

These are a couple of more general expressions, not necessarily only used for celebration.

> ***Don't cross that bridge until you get there.***

And, of course,

> ***Don't get ahead of yourself.***

Which is the most general case for situations you describe.

Answer (score -1):

**Nothing is carved in stone.**

Meaning we haven't written the future, we write the past and the future can be changed.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to get carried away when you've put all your eggs in one basket. It's best to not get your hopes up until you know it's a done deal.